# Rails 3 / Ajax - Turning link_to into a Jquery link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to change a hyperlink into a ajax link. That way I can link to an external target while updating model data without having to send the user to a custom controller action to handle a post/redirect.

My application is a basic image gallery, each image links to an external website:

Here's my partial _pictures.html.erb:

```
<% @galleries.each do |g| %>
    <% for image in g.images %>
    <div id="picture">
      <%= render 'top_nav'%>

      <%= link_to g.source, :target => true do %>
        <%= image_tag image.file_url(:preview) %>
      <% end %>

      <%= will_paginate(@galleries, :next_label => "Forward", :previous_label => "Previous") %>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="image_description">
      <h2>
      <%= g.title %>,
      <span class="time">
        <%= distance_of_time_in_words(g.created_at, Time.now, include_seconds = false)%> ago
      </span>
      </h2>
    </div>      
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which is rendered on my index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Share and click images to unlock more...</h1>

<div id="galleries">
<%= render 'pictures' %>
</div>
```

I believe I've been able to change the link into an ajax link with the follow in application.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#picture a").live("click", function() {

    return false;
  });
});
```

As the link_to doesn't work (which I expected). Now, I'm trying to write the handler(not sure if that's the correct word) in the index.js.erb, I know this is way wrong, but what I've pieced together is:

```
$("#picture").html.("<%= escape_javascript(render)("pictures")) %>")
```

How do I get this link back working, but with via javascript? And if I wanted to make an ajax call to a model method, where would I begin writing that code, in application.js or index.js.erb?

Obligatory defense mechanism: I suck at javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#picture a").live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the click from linking anywhere

        $.ajax({
            url:'/my_ajax_file.erb',
            dataType:'html',
            data: $(this).attr('id'), // send whatever here...
            type: 'post',
            success:function(data){
                $('#picture').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try    `$("#picture").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("pictures")) %>");`

but if you use prototype and jquery change $ for jQuery.noConflict()

```
  $(function() {
      $("#picture a").live("click", function() {
          $.getScript(this.href);
          return false;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help (everyone). Working with this, I seem to be having successful ajax links, as my pagination links are no longer changing the URL and are working. The external links though do nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to have in your controller something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html do
      redirect_to #whatever you normally redirect to for html
   end
   format.js do
      render :json => some_json_thing #this will get passed back as the data element in the ajax callback above
   end
end
```